# $\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

What is the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$?  I tried it in different ways but failed every single attempt I tried with n * n+1 summation formula but as the multiplication is in the denominator how could I find it ? 
 What is the shortest form to arrive at the answer?

Comment: learn mathjax for your next post

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$T_r = \dfrac{1}{r} - \dfrac{1}{r+1}$

Therefore the sum telescopes.

Answer (score 2):

Your sum is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{100}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$$

$$=1-\frac{1}{101}$$

By telescopage.

Answer (score 2):

Is a telescopic one:

$$\frac{1}{n*(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Then use this to all the fractions and you get that is $1-\frac{1}{101}=\frac{100}{101}$